# C# Автозапуск приложения из реестра

Tags: c#, реестр

Записываю в реестр значение:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("x64host",  Path.GetTempPath() + "\x64host.exe");
```

В реестре ,в пути к файлу не правильное название файла,как исправить

[image: реестр]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заменить `"\x64host"` на `@"\x64host"` или на `"\\x64host"`, так как `"\"` - [спецсимвол](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: блин,а почему антивирус распознает программу как троян?

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников вы меня спрашиваете в вопросе про работу со строками, почему код, который вы не показывали, определяется антивирусом, который вы не называли, как вредоносный? Я не знаю :)

Comment: если вам мой ответ помог решить проблему - пожалуйста, отметье его как правильный. Если у вас есть дополнительны вопросы, но уже на другую тему - имеет смысл задать их отдельными вопросами.

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников Старайтесь следовать принципу "Один вопрос -- один ответ". Вопрос про ложные срабатывания антивируса лучше задайте отдельно.

Comment: Я то отметил,просто это весь код программы ,просто создать запись в реестре

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников: Ну, ваша программа пытается прописать автоматический запуск другой программы в реестр. Причём эта самая другая программа лежит во временном каталоге. Это и вправду выглядит _крайне_ подозрительно.